# How do I display part of another website in an iframe and continue through it to have someone check out via a cart

Tags: html, css, iframe, cart

Another question related to building this website. Currently, the domain I am working on is only serving as a landing page. Then users click to go to another site where they actually make their purchase.

I have constructed a website to actually use for this domain and hope to have the brands separate so that there can be brand recognition of only this at this domain.

The issue is that the cart is under the other domain name. It is hosted by a place that is dirt cheap and my boss is not likely to move from.

Is it possible to use iframes on the site I am working on to display portions of the other site and have it allow people to purchase items while not feeling like they are being redirected to another site?

The site that has the cart will need styling changes which is not an issue. I just want to know if it is feasible or not.

Current domain is http://www.betterbullets.com and the place the bullets are actually sold is http://www.kingshooters.com/better-bullets-c-463.html

Obviously the title and links on the side need not be displayed on the website I am designing.

Any help or pointers that you could give would be great.

So far all I've got was to take the code from the website and integrate it into a new html document on the domain I'm working on. But I'm not sure how that will work for the cart portion or if that is even feasible.

I was using code like this:

```
 <div style="border: none; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: auto;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="betterbullets1.html" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 700px; margin-top: 0px; width: 975px;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain issues are about the communication between iframes. You can always embed any iframe but, if domains differ, iframes cannot interact with each other e.g. execute JS, modify DOM etc.

HTML5 provides a sandbox property that re-enables particular features of the cross-domain iframe interaction. Be careful, it can be dangerous.

Hope this helped :)